Suppressing the message "Application Error. Please report this error to the app developer" in Android Automotive app
An Android Automotive app that was working fine in my car a couple months ago doesn't start correctly now. The screen says "Application Error. Please report this error to the app developer" and there is a button that says "Close Application". I cannot reproduce this in a debug build on the emulator, but I see it in a production build on both the emulator (Android 12 and 13) and vehicle (Android 12). Previous versions of the app that worked fine in the past also have this issue.
When I open it in the emulator, I can see the following crash stack trace:
Serialization failure in getAppInfo
androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundler$TracedBundlerException: Class to deserialize is missing a no args constructor: androidx.car.app.FailureResponse, frames: [FailureResponse, FailureResponse]
at androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundler.serializeObject(Unknown Source:125)
at androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundler.toBundle(Unknown Source:285)
at androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundleable.androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundler.toBundle(SourceFile:7)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.RemoteProxyInputConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundleable.create(Unknown Source:25)
androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$sendFailureResponseToHost$4
androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$00787579f7b110f935892f6d3a11e0cf6af59cc35bc9b41a1e55d24116f40963$0.call$bridge
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallToHostForResult(Unknown Source:36)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallToHost(Unknown Source:0)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.sendFailureResponseToHost(Unknown Source:12)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.RemoteProxyInputConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$sendSuccessResponseToHost$3(Unknown Source:71)
androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$00787579f7b110f935892f6d3a11e0cf6af59cc35bc9b41a1e55d24116f40963$0.call$bridge
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallToHostForResult(Unknown Source:36)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallToHost(Unknown Source:0)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DebugStringsKt.androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.sendSuccessResponseToHost(Unknown Source:12)
at androidx.car.app.CarAppService$CarAppBinder.getAppInfo(Unknown Source:11)
at androidx.car.app.ICarApp$Stub.onTransact(Unknown Source:58)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: androidx.car.app.FailureResponse.<init> []
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
at androidx.car.app.serialization.Bundler.serializeObject(Unknown Source:15)

All of this code is in the Jetpack Car App library and I don't call any of this code directly from my app. This stack trace is not being reported as a crash on Google Play or in my crash tracking software, so I believe Jetpack has its own handling for this type of crash.

This appears to be an issue with the androidx.car library version 1.2.0 that was not present before April 2024, but has taken effect at the time of my testing in June 2024. It affects apps using Templates,  CarAppService, and CarAppActivity.
A new version of the androidx.car library, 1.4.0, was released on May 29, 2024 that addresses this issue. Additionally, the vehicle or emulators with the Google Play Store may need to update the Google Automotive App Host app. For the API 33 emulator that does not include the Google Play Store, you may need to update to Android Automotive with Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image API 33 (revision 3).
